# VS2022 [C# , .NET 6] reference third party .dll with path, instead of including in build

Tags: c#, dll, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

We are working on a project that uses image/object detection. The third party .dlls are huge. We are talking 2-3 GB in total.
I would like to reference these .dlls in a way that the application at runtime uses a path e.g. C:\externalLibs to look for the referenced .dlls and load them into memory.

I know about the properties to not copy it locally "Copy local - false" but that doesn't seem to work. Also I can't even find all of the mentioned dlls in the properties.

I can provide more information if needed, just ask ahead! :)

Comment: Are those .net assemblies or native dlls?

Comment: Those are .net assemblies. We are talking about Emgu CV, specifically the CUDA .dlls